# AngularJS transclude HTML attributes inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive:

```
.directive("radio", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "EA",
            replace: true,
            scope: { text: "@", name: "@", value: "&" },
            template: '<label class="radio" for="{{name}}">\
                    <span class="icons">\
                        <span class="first-icon fui-radio-unchecked"></span>\
                        <span class="second-icon fui-radio-checked"></span>\
                    </span>\
                    <input type="radio" id="{{name}}" name="{{name}}" value="{{value}}" ng-model="value" />\
                    <span ng-bind="text"></span>\
                </label>',
            link: function (scope, el) {
                scope.value = false;
                scope.$watch("value", function (value) {
                    value ? el.addClass("checked") : el.removeClass("checked");
                });
            }
        };
    })
```

Right now I use it like:

```
<radio name="test" value="testvalue"></radio>
```

I don't like having to add scope variables everytime I want to add something, it would be nice if I could do:

```
<radio id="{{name}}" name="{{name}}" value="{{value}}" ng-model="value" required></radio>
```

And have the resulting HTML would be:

```
<label class="radio" for="{{name}}">
    <span class="icons">
        <span class="first-icon fui-radio-unchecked"></span>
        <span class="second-icon fui-radio-checked"></span>
    </span>
    <input type="radio" id="{{name}}" name="{{name}}" value="{{value}}" ng-model="value" required />
        <span ng-bind="text"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

The link function has an `attrs` variable that represents the attributes in the directive tag. You can work with that and insert data into necessary tags. But you won't be able to nicely do 2way binding without scope variables